# Django duplicate file to all the records with M2M which is self referencing

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Serializer & APIview where i upload a file it should be uploaded to other related records as well.

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 122)
    related_records = models.ManyToManyField('self', null = True)

class RecordDocument(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record, related_name = 'documents', null = True, 
                    blank= True )
    file = models.FileField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)



class RecordDocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    save_documents_to_related_records = serializers.BooleanField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = RecordDocument
        fields = ( 'save_documents_to_related_records', 'file', 
                   'record' )
   

class RecordDocumentUploadView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    'how do i get serializers field **save_documents_to_related_records** and save 
     the file on  **related_records** which is not used in serializer till now if 
     there are any inside it'
```

Comment: What is the `upload_to_related_cases` field in the serializer? I can't see any reference to it.

Comment: Hello @DavidLu Sorry My bad i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
class RecordDocumentUploadView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RecordDocumentSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            input_data = serializer.validated_data
            flag = input_data.pop('save_documents_to_related_records')                
            new_document = RecordDocument.objects.create(**input_data)
            if flag:
                ...
        else:
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I am sorry u misunderstood the question David i am able to upload the document already and that functionality is working fine but here when i uplaod a document to a record it should show a checkbox .i.e save_documents_to_related_records so when flag is set to True it should also save the document in the other related records i.e related_records field in the model Record

Comment: but logic is in APIView post method.

Comment: I changed my answer. Please check again. I set the `flag` variable, and added the `if` condition.